# What are the advantages of studying the dual problem in linear programming?

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, linear-programming

I am studying linear programming and I came across `primal-dual` algorithm in `Linear Programming`. I understood it but I am unable to understand why there is a need to calculate a dual, if problem can be solved in primal space. Are there some inherent advantages?

I am fine with the proofs of weak duality and strong duality but I just wonder that what is the reason.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: A [related question](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/19389/1037) from the theoretical computer science perspective.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here are some uses of the dual problem.

1. **Understanding the dual problem leads to specialized algorithms for some important classes of linear programming problems.**  Examples include the transportation simplex method, the Hungarian algorithm for the assignment problem, and the network simplex method.  Even column generation relies partly on duality.
2. **The dual can be helpful for sensitivity analysis.**  Changing the primal's right-hand side constraint vector or adding a new constraint to it can make the original primal optimal solution infeasible.  However,  this only changes the objective function or adds a new variable to the dual, respectively, so the original dual optimal solution is still feasible (and is usually not far from the new dual optimal solution).
3. **Sometimes finding an initial feasible solution to the dual is much easier than finding one for the primal.**  For example, if the primal is a minimization problem, the constraints are often of the form $A {\bf x} \geq {\bf b}$, ${\bf x} \geq {\bf 0}$, for ${\bf b} \geq {\bf 0}$.  The dual constraints would then likely be of the form $A^T {\bf y} \leq {\bf c}$, ${\bf y} \geq {\bf 0}$, for ${\bf c} \geq {\bf 0}$.  The origin is feasible for the latter problem but not for the former.
4. **The dual variables give the shadow prices for the primal constraints.**  Suppose you have a profit maximization problem with a resource constraint $i$.  Then the value $y_i$ of the corresponding dual variable in the optimal solution tells you that you get an increase of $y_i$ in the maximum profit for each unit increase in the amount of resource $i$ (absent degeneracy and for small increases in resource $i$).
5. **Sometimes the dual is just easier to solve.**  Aseem Dua mentions this: A problem with many constraints and few variables can be converted into one with few constraints and many variables.

Answer (score 2):

Duality provides a lot of computational advantage in a problem with lesser number of variables and a multitude of constraints.

Take the example of simplex, you will notice it is much easier to deal with lesser basic variables.

Economists have an interpretation (wiki article has a section) that defines the dual variables nicely. On another front, duality gives a better understanding of the situation and may offer certain more perspectives.